# Do a OR in PHP Variable?

Tags: php, if-statement

I seen it around and not sure if it was in JS or PHP but if it was possible in PHP that would be great! If not, how would i go about it without a IF, if not possible without one then how do i go about it with one?

Code:

```
$myvar = str_replace("hello","jpg",$myvar) || str_replace("hello","gif",$myvar); //Didnt work
```

And i tried:

```
$myvar = (str_replace("hello","jpg",$myvar) || str_replace("hello","gif",$myvar)); //Didnt work
```

Basically what i am trying to achieve here is to run whatever one that comes back true.
If it cant do: `str_replace("hello","jpg",$myvar)` then do `str_replace("hi","gif",$myvar)`. Now i tried doing a IF but that also didnt work.

My IF that also didnt work:

```
if (str_replace("hello","jpg",$myvar) == true)
{
    $myvar = str_replace("hello","jpg",$myvar);
}
else if (str_replace("hello","gif",$myvar) == true)
{
    $myvar = str_replace("hello","gif",$myvar);
}
```

Comment: You could probably just use `strpos() !== false` to check, then use `str_replace()`. See the manual for `strpos()` usage: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Your code makes no sense; `str_replace()` doesn't return a boolean.

Comment: According to to [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), `str_replace` returns _This function returns a string or an array with the replaced values._ So, it will never evaluate to `false`.

Comment: I understand it doesnt return a boolean but how do i go about achieving what i am trying to do?

Comment: You can use arrays as args to `str_replace` btw ~ ie: `$myvar=str_replace( array('hello','hi'), array('jpg','gif'), $myvar );`

Comment: Start reading the documentation of the commands you use... http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution is:

```
// if you have `hello` in a string - replace it
if (strpos($myvar, 'hello') !== false) {
    $myvar = str_replace("hello","jpg",$myvar);
} else {
    // else replace `hi`, 
    // if there's no `hi` in a string - it doesn't matter
    $myvar = str_replace("hi","gif",$myvar);
}
```

Comment: Great Idea but realised my string will never have hi in it only hello. +1 though.

Answer (score 2):

```
$myvar = (strpos($myvar, 'hello') !== false) ? str_replace('hello', 'jpg', $myvar) : str_replace('hi', 'gif', $myvar);
```

OR

```
if (strpos($myvar, 'hello') !== false)
{
     $myvar = str_replace('hello', 'jpg', $myvar);
}
elseif (strpos($myvar, 'hi') !== false)
{
     $myvar = str_replace('hi', 'gif', $myvar);
}
```

Comment: Great Idea but realized my string will never have hi in it but only hello. I updated my question. Didnt even notice the typo! +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use an array:

```
$myvar = str_replace(array('hello', 'hi'), array('jpg', 'gif'), $myvar);
```